# Azure CI container per customer

Tags: docker, azure-aks, azure-container-instances

I have a monolithic application based on .NET , the application itself is a web based app.
I am looking at multiple articles and trying to figure out if the Azure CI or similar would be an correct service to use.
The application will run 24/7 and i guess this is where confusion comes in, wouldn't it be normal to have **always on** application running on CI?
What i am trying to achieve is a container per customer where each customer gets one or more instances that he owns. The other question would be costs and scalability, i would expect to have thousands of containers so perhaps i should be looking at Kubernetes ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding. I'm pretty new to both ACI and Kubernetes, so treat this as a suggestions and not a definitive answers .

Azure Container Instances is a quick, easy and cheap way to run a single-instance of a container in Azure. However, it doesn't scale very well on its own (it can scale up, but not out, and not automatically..), and it lacks the many container-orchestration features that kubernetes offers.

Kubernetes offers a lot more, such as zero-downtime deployments, scaling out with multiple replicates, and many more features. It is also a lot more complex, costs more, and takes much longer to set up.

I think ACI is a bit too simple to meet your use-case.